# Can I use the annotation @TargetApi with intellij?

Tags: intellij-idea

Intellij keeps telling me cannot resolve a symbol.
But on eclipse the same code works fine.
I set the minSdkVersion to be 16 and imported the relevant class.
Is this feature not supported? I am using Intellij 13.